# MATLAB function importdata acting weird

Tags: matlab

I have a text file with numbers that looks like this:

a.txt

0.001240242769

-0.000829468827

-0.0001689229831

0.0008228798977

-3.86881172e-05

in a MATLAB I used to be able to use

```
x_in = importdata('a.txt');
```

and x_in was in fact a vector of 5 double numbers.
I don't know what I changed yesterday but all of a sudden when I use the same function it downloads as char

x_in='0.001240242769
-0.000829468827
-0.0001689229831
0.0008228798977
-3.86881172e-05'

What did I change and how can I fix it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely cause is that the text file has something that is not recognized as number or delimiter. I would suggest to use `load` as following:

```
x_in = load('a.txt', '-ascii');
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, load seems to be working fine, the weird thing is that is a text file I have been reading using importdata for months and has not changed, and only today it stopped working. I still can't figure out what changed

Comment: Were you using the same OS, or changing between Windows and unix?

Comment: same computer, same matlab version. it really baffles me